# GAUL: Genetic Algorithm Utility Library has anyone use it in a C# solution?

Tags: c#

The GAUL library is the library used for Pgrouting to do some of its functions. Has anyone use this library in a C# solution?

If you do, do you have the wrappers needed for this or could you point me in the right direction to create those?